# Convert Python byte to "unsigned 8 bit integer"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading in a byte array/list from socket.  I want Python to treat the first byte as an "unsigned 8 bit integer".  How is it possible to get its integer value as an unsigned 8 bit integer?

Comment: If you are willing to take a dependency on `numpy`, some of their functions take a `dtype` arg, which you can set to `numpy.uint8`.

Example: `bytestream = numpy.fromfile(infile, dtype=numpy.uint8)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/struct.html#module-struct) module.

```
import struct
value = struct.unpack('B', data[0:1])[0]
```

We have to specify a range of 1 (`0:1`), because Python 3 converts automatically to an integer otherwise.

Note that unpack always returns a tuple, even if you're only unpacking one item.

Also, have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591920/python-binary-data-reading).

Comment: so what is stored in struct.unpack('B', data[0])[1]?

Comment: data[0] is the first byte that you receive. unpack("B", data[0]) treats that byte as a 8-bit unsigned integer (known as unsigned char in C) and returns a tuple containing that integer (had you passed two bytes to unpack you would do something like unpack("BB", data[0:2]) and get a 2-tuple back). The final [0] gets the first (and only) item in the tuple.

Comment: In this case, it’s a tuple with one element, so struct.unpack('B', data[0])[1] will raise an IndexError. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879914/decoding-packed-data-into-a-structure/1880563#1880563][Here] is an example of a typical use of struct.

Answer (score 11):

bytes/bytearray is a sequence of integers. If you just access an element by its index you'll have an integer:

```
>>> b'abc'
b'abc'
>>> _[0]
97
```

By their very definition, bytes and bytearrays contain integers in the `range(0, 256)`. So they're "unsigned 8-bit integers".

Comment: for example, i have this in my server side code

data = conn.recv(1000000)

as long as i understand i receive bytes... so i want data[0] to be treated as "unsigned 8 bit integer". how is this possible?

Comment: This only works in Python 3.x. Python 2.6 has the b'string literal' syntax, but it is merely an alias for str, and older versions will give you a SyntaxError.

Comment: @musicinmybrain: that's why this question is tagged as `python-3.x` I guess

Answer (score 7):

Another very reasonable and simple option, if you just need the first byte’s integer value, would be something like the following:

```
value = ord(data[0])
```

If you want to unpack all of the elements of your received data at once (and they’re not just a homogeneous array), or if you are dealing with multibyte objects like 32-bit integers, then you’ll need to use something like the struct module.