# How to read a byte and convert to int(0-255)

Tags: python-2.7

I want to read an image byte per byte and get the (0-255) value of each byte.I tried to print with this code:

```
f = open("my_directory_with_image.png", "rb")
try:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
        print int(byte)
finally:
    f.close()
```

But i get this error:

> *invalid literal for int() with base 10:*

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#module-struct) module.

```
import struct
value = struct.unpack('B', byte[0])[0]
```

Unpack will always return a tuple, even if you're only unpacking one item.

Also this seems like a duplicate of [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887506/convert-python-byte-to-unsigned-8-bit-integer)